# PHP $_GET stopped working

Tags: php, get

So i've been using $_GET to access articles by passing the article ID through the URL and reading this id in the next page so that all the values relating to the article can be drawn.

The passing code is as follows

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<td><a href="Article.php?id=' . $row['ArticleID']. '"><img class="cover" src="' . $row['CoverImage']. '"></a></td>';
```

While there are articles, get the images, make the images links and then when the image is clicked append "id=#" to the end of the url.

And as expected, when the link is clicked i get this.

```
www.r3gamers.com/Article.php?id=1
```

All seems fine so far, and yet using this code to then retrieve the id and place it in a variable

```
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) {
        $articleid = $_GET['id'];
    } elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ) {
        $articleid = $_POST['id'];
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>'; exit();
    }
```

Always ends up with the error returned, it can't see the value even though it has been successfully appended to the URL, and i can't tell why.

It's worth stating that this exact code was working fine on the live website up until today, i made no changes to the code (except moving the header into an inclusion file, a header which has no effect on this piece of code) and there seems to be no reason that it has stopped. 
For safe measure, i even reverted to code that was over a week old (WAY before the error started happening), and that hasn't fixed the error.

EDIT: in response to replies, i've tested the script with var_dump($_GET) which returns "Empty".

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
This suggestion however gives no feedback (that i can find) at all presumably meaning that no errors with the script are found?

EDIT3: As no errors have been found, i created two fairly simple files to test that getters and setters are working.

testset.php

```
<a href="testget.php?id=1"><img class="cover" src="Pictures/TheLastOfUs/Cover.jpg"></a>
```

testget.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

This results in this output

```
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

And just to ensure that it actually is working i tried a different value

```
array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'thisisatestid' (length=13)
```

Surely this means that it's not my project that's "broken" but at worst just the one or two files mentioned above? (probably just article.php)?

EDIT4: Even further testing (changing the initial link from article.php?id=" .row .... " to testget.php?id=" .row .... " shows that index is definitely still working as expected, outputting the generated ID's via var_dump

So, it's just the article.php page that's the problem then.

EDIT5: VAR_DUMP($_GET); on "Article.php" now retrieves the id from the URL but the GET test does not, so it's still not working (although i feel progress is being made, finally)

EDIT6: I've managed to get the id passing working perfectly on localhost, and yet after uploading the new working copy to godaddy, it still doesn't work. The $_GET value is being passed as checked by var_dump, but the getter isn't succeeding (ironically) because it can't find a get value ... which makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Are you testing on your localhost or on your domain? Did you upload the updated code to the server?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_GET)` and share the contents.

Comment: Yes and yes, i test on localhost and if happy i upload it to the server and test it there to make sure it works the same, in this case, it didn't.

Comment: If you really don't know if it will be in $_POST or $_GET you can use $_REQUEST. But you should always know where it's coming from.

Comment: Quick look at the website i'd say something is wrong with the database connection or queries, and that the `if` statement is working as expected, since even in the main page you are losing ids and images from those articles

Comment: Also, as @miken32 said, if you need to catch either _GET or _POST value of the id variable, you could simply use `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: var dump gives empty both on localhost (which questions why the hell it is working then ... it's not cached, i hard refresh every few attempts especially with errors) and on the server.

Comment: @kypros i know it's not working fully on the server, it was working but after finding that the article page wasn't working and reverting to old files the rows (numbered) misaligned, which is why the background is the image that's supposed to be in the small boxes and the boxes are empty. the article should still be readable, even if it brings a lot of MYSQLI errors.

Comment: @Kypros I've fixed the homepage on the website so it's easier to understand what's meant to be where (hopefully) and see what is broken and what isn't (it's not as bad as it initially looked, promise)

Comment: You have rewrites on the server? Check `.htaccess`

Comment: Surely if it's not working on localhost now as well (i have no idea why it was working last night) then the .htaccess file on the server can't be the issue?

Comment: Post your .htaccess. Be sure to add the `QSA` flag to it

Comment: @DarkBee Where would i find the .htaccess file? I've looked in the file location and in the wampserver folders and can't see it. 
Is it possible that i don't have an .htaccess file? or is it something that's generated on project creation?

Comment: what FTP program are u using? Some FTP programs hide `.htaccess`files by default.

Comment: @DarkBee FileTranserProtocol? None that i'm aware of. Wampserver runs straight from the local machine, no file transfer needed.

Answer (score 2):

Too many parentheses; try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   $articleid = $_GET['id'];
}else{
   echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>'; 
   exit();
}
```

Also, if you know for sure that you are accessing the id variable through a GET, there is no reason to try for a POST, so get rid of that extra code.

You mentioned something about inclusion files? Place this code at the beginning of the script, and it might give you some errors that you need to see so that you know what the problem is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If there are any server-side PHP related errors, that will output them for you and let you know what's going on.

**EDIT**:
At this point, I have to imagine your hosting service updated their servers or made some modifcations to where you can't access the $_GET request variables without using something more secure. This all might be an enhanced security feature. Try this:

```
$articleid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');

if(!$articleid || !is_numeric($articleid)){
   echo '<p class="error">This page has not been properly accessed.</p>';
   exit;
}
```

Comment: This didn't help although i agree looking back at it the outside most parenthesis weren't needed at all, POST may or may not be needed, i haven't decided yet so i thought it didn't hurt to have it. 

The inc file mentioned is literally a black bar header and has absolutely nothing to do with the database at all, let alone getters, setters and anything else. It's just links. 

The error reporting doesn't appear to give anything at all.

Comment: The edit didn't work either. I don't think it's anything about security of the hosting service, because it doesn't work on localhost either now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ) {
    $articleid = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't solve it (i'd have been pissed off if it did tbh)

Comment: @edrich I don't really get why you say that. [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) is part of the language.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer but I personally think you should have simply included this as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @iLot Your question is not relevant here but here's a link explaining the difference and the need for it: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php